# What footprint does a C# WebBrowser control (wpf) leave for the web host

Tags: c#, wpf, web-controls

Sorry if the title of the question is a little misleading but I was struggling to fit what I am asking into a single sentance.

I have recently written an app to automate a bunch of administrative tasks I have to perform on a website, its WPF and makes use of the System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control.  I am fairly happy with what I have so far it is saving me lots of time.  However, whether using automation on this website is allowed or not is a bit of a grey area.  I have read the terms of use quite closely and it states that any automation must follow the rules of the robots.txt file.  They have also neglected to create a robots.txt file.

I have a valid account with this website and I can just as easily achieve the same result by sitting in front of my machine and manually doing the same thing, I don't feel like I am breaking any rules really.  It has got me thinking though, what information does this control leave behind?  Can the web hosts detect the automation and are there ways around it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you've built a kinda bot that performs **ADMINISTRATIVE** tasks for you on your website, hosted by some hosting provider, right?

And you claim that you can achieve the same result, albeit slower, by performing the said task yourself.

If you're simply automating the task, then the memory "footprint" in the host is the same as if you were doing the task yourself.

However, there are ways to detect the use of a bot, that is, repetitive tasks that is being processed far faster than a human being could do. That's one way how they detect the usage of bots in, say, WoW.

Comment: I like how you made the word aministrative bold and in caps.  I thought I had spelled it incorrectly or something :)  Yes you got the gist.  I can indeed provide the same result myself, not neccesarily any quicker either.  The code waits for pages to load each time and then parses out the required buttons or links ... clicks them then waits for the page to load again.  It's still worthwhile as I can run it overnight.

Comment: Whoops hit return before I was ready.  So is that a definate then?  There is no way from their web logs that the web hosts can see what browser I was using or any information like that?  Thanks for your response.

Comment: The point with the admin tasks is just to twarts the fact that there are a number of other possibilities (many of them is a grey area of the law)... Anyway, if you're using the C# WebBrowser, then, you're using the Trident Engine, that is, the Internet Explorer underneth your program.